# Very old, crispy font in certain UIs in Windows 11

Tags: fonts, windows-11, user-interface

I've installed Windows 11 today on one of my machines and I have noticed that LICEcap (and some other apps) has a very old, crispy font in certain elements of the UI. A font that I remember back in Windows 95 or even Windows 3.1, so ages ago:

[image]

It's not only very ugly, but (as you can see) it prevents me from accessing certain configuration options and fields.

I don't know what is this. I have never met something like that in my previous experience (Windows 10, Windows 7). Can anyone advice on what can be done here to fix this?

Comment: Most likely the programs are trying to use a font that no longer exists on Win11 and thus they get a fallback font.

Comment: Doesn't happen on Windows 10. Have you downloaded LICEcap from the [official website](https://www.cockos.com/licecap/)?

Comment: @harrymc Must be something with my graphic driver or particular Windows 11 installation. After fresh install of a system problem is solved. Care for crafting an answer (that shouldn't happen in neither W11 nor newest version of LICEcap)? Or rather we should close this question as "can't reproduce"?

Comment: I added an answer, in case this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't happen on Windows 10 and with newer versions of LICEcap,
so this indicates some problem with Windows setup.

The poster solved the problem by reinstalling Windows.

Here are some alternatives to try before that:

- Test Windows integrity by running
  [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html)
  and then
  [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
- [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html)